# How do I get the values from a method which returns two dimensional array?

Tags: java

```
private double[][] getTimeValuePairsArray(List<Double> timeList, List<Double> valueList){
    double[][] timeValuePairs = new double[2][timeList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < timeList.size(); ++i) {
        timeValuePairs[0][i] = ((Double)timeList.get(i)).doubleValue();
        timeValuePairs[1][i] = ((Double)valueList.get(i)).doubleValue();
    }
    return timeValuePairs;      
}
```

`timeList` and `valueList` are `ArrayList` objects and contains some data.

```
double[][] timeValuePairs1 = getTimeValuePairsArray(timeList, valueList);

//here i want to display values which is returned by the above method.
```

Comment: [Java tutorials: Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: So just access the values and display them. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(timeValuePairs1[0][i]);
    System.out.println(timeValuePairs1[1][i]);
}
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeValuePairs1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < timeValuePairs1[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(timeValuePairs1[i][j]);
    }
}
```